# Angular- TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am currently watchin a tutorial, and I'm really keeping an eye on what's going on.
However, I am constantly getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

This is my part of code where I get that:

```
onSubmit(){
this.service.register().subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    if (res.succeeded){
      this.service.formModel.reset();
      this.toastr.success('Korisnik kreiran!', 'Registracija uspješna!');
    } else {
      res.errors.forEach((element:any)=>{
        switch (element.code){
          case 'DuplicateUserName':
            this.toastr.error('Korisničko ime se već koristi.', 'Neuspjela registracija.');
          break;
            //Registration failed
          default:
            this.toastr.error(element.description, 'Neuspjela registracija.');
          break;
        }
      });
    }
  },
  err=>{
    console.log(err);
  }
);
}
```

Does anybody has idea what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: It means there is no errors property in your response.

Comment: Your tutorial seems to be out of sync with the project's angular version.

Answer (score 1):

```
onSubmit(){
this.service.register().subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    if (res.succeeded){
      this.service.formModel.reset();
      this.toastr.success('Korisnik kreiran!', 'Registracija uspješna!');
    } else {
    if ('errors' in res) {
      res.errors.forEach((element:any)=>{
        switch (element.code){
          case 'DuplicateUserName':
            this.toastr.error('Korisničko ime se već koristi.', 'Neuspjela registracija.');
          break;
            //Registration failed
          default:
            this.toastr.error(element.description, 'Neuspjela registracija.');
          break;
        }
      });
     }
    }
  },
  err=>{
    console.log(err);
  }
);
}
```

Adding an `if` block before you loop through `errors` should resolve the issue. Still let me know if you are still facing any issue.